# Cumulative Average

Tags: powerbi, sql-server-data-tools, dax

I've tried a few things and maybe I've burnt out my mind on how this should work 
basically Over a 12 Month, rolling I wanted to accumulate a total. 
Columns are 
**Month**,
**Head count** (this is a distinctcount of users) 
**Head count divided** (Head count Dived by 12 ) 
**Cumulative Head Count** (adding the returned rows of head count)

[image]
Cumulative is not adding the row up not matter what I try and i'v looked at all the code out there. Is it something to do with the headcount being distinct?

```
Cumulative Headcount:=
CALCULATE (
   [Head Count Divided],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Date'[Date]),
       'Date'[Date] <= MAX ( ('Date'[Date] ) )
    )
```

)

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 0):

If this is the result you're looking for...

[image]

...here's one way to get it, using DAX:

```
Cumulative Head Count = CALCULATE(SUMX(Table10,Table10[Head Count]),filter(Table10,Table10[Year Month Name]<=EARLIER(Table10[Year Month Name],1)))
```

*(Replace the instances of "Table10" in the code with your table's name. Also make sure your 'Year Month Name' column is formatted as a date and your 'Head Count' column is formatted as a number.)*

You could replace `[Head Count]` with `[Head Count Divided]` to get a cumulative summation of the "Head Count Divided" values, if that is what you're looking for instead.

Comment: Hi @marc pincince
I cannot get the Earlier function to work in your code line 
is this because my Headcount is a measure and the date table that it is scanning is unaware of the Earlier date ? 
_EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist._
I understand what your code is doing but cannot solve this issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know whether it is the use of a measure that is causing your problem. Have you tried (*can you try*) using a column instead of the measure? *If you can use a column*, that might at least answer the question as to whether the measure is the issue. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.